# How to read data from this json format

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am stuck on this. This is a json_encoded string by the Wordpress plugin and saved into database.
I want to read it from my own database query. I am getting `null` when tried with `var_dump` .
It has some properties of code which is creating problem, I think.

Below is the data where from i want to read usable data for my use. I am using PHP and Mysql.

`a:3:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:3:"100";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:1;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:3:"200";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:2;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:8:"Infinite";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:1;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}}`

I know this looks nasty but copy and try to decode it.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ It is not a valid json format

Comment: Looks to me it is a serialized object

Comment: @KA_lin So, if it is not a valid format. Is there anyway to read data from it.

Comment: Use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: $object = unserialize($yourString);

Comment: @KA_lin I tried with `unserialize()` but didn't work.

Comment: You need to have loaded all the required class definitions before unserializing: in this case, the `WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes` class

Comment: @SudheerPal: Where do you get the JSON from?

Comment: @AmalMurali From the database table of quiz plugin WP-pro-quiz.

Comment: @MarkBaker I also think so but i am doing all this out of wp-content folder of wordpress and the structure of WpProQuiz is MVC. I can make object when i include all that files.But i am weak in MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh In Wordpress you can do as follows

```
$serialized = 'a:3:{i:0;s:5:"examp";i:1;s:6:"exampl";i:2;s:6:"examp2";}';
var_dump(unserialize($serialized));

Array
(
    [0] => examp
    [1] => exampl
    [2] => examp2
)
```

Comment: How is this going to work if the posted data is not *even* valid JSON?

Comment: @AmalMurali is there anyway to change into valid format to print data from it.

Comment: Err what? What does `phpserialize` have to do with the question (or even PHP for that matter)? It's a `a port of the serialize and unserialize functions of php to python.`

Comment: Did you run the code before posting the answer? It will produce an error. See [this](http://3v4l.org/apgI6).